# Making a navigation header menu with bulma, need some advice

Tags: menus, navigation

I'm relatively new to wordpress and php and currently I'm in the weeds trying to wrap my head around creating a custom navigation menu using the structure and css instructions provided by bulma.

Wordpress doesn't seem to nest collections, so I'm forced to first "unwind" the know so to speak by iterating through the pre-existing navgation menu array and create my own parent to child relations storing the child collection in an array.

```
function generateMenuItems($collection) {    
$menu_items = array();
$child_id = 0;
$parent_id = 0;

foreach( $collection as $menu_item ) {

     if (!$menu_item->menu_item_parent) {
        $parent_id = $menu_item->ID;

        $upperMostParent = array(
            "id" => $parent_id,
            "parent_id" => $menu_item->menu_item_parent,
            "title" => $menu_item->title,
            "link" => $menu_item->url,
            "children" => array()
        );
        $menu_items[] = $upperMostParent;
     }

     if ($parent_id == $menu_item->menu_item_parent) {

        $child_id = $menu_item->ID;
        $child = array(
            "id" => $child_id,
            "parent_id" => $menu_item->menu_item_parent,
            "title" => $menu_item->title,
            "link" => $menu_item->url,
            "children" => array()
        );

        $parentIndex = array_search($parent_id, array_column($menu_items, "id"));

        $menu_items[$parentIndex]["children"][] = $child_1;

     }  
 }//end of foreach loop.
   return $menu_items;
}//end of function.
```

The above code outputs the current vardump:

```
 array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Home"
    ["link"]=>
    string(17) "http://localhost/"
    ["children"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(7)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "Guides"
    ["link"]=>
    string(29) "http://localhost/sample-page/"
    ["children"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(13)
        ["parent_id"]=>
        string(1) "7"
        ["title"]=>
        string(9) "New World"
        ["link"]=>
        string(29) "http://localhost/sample-page/"
        ["children"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(14)
        ["parent_id"]=>
        string(1) "7"
        ["title"]=>
        string(5) "Squad"
        ["link"]=>
        string(29) "http://localhost/sample-page/"
        ["children"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(15)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["title"]=>
    string(11) "Sample Page"
    ["link"]=>
    string(29) "http://localhost/sample-page/"
    ["children"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(42)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "Events"
    ["link"]=>
    string(24) "http://localhost/events/"
    ["children"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(45)
        ["parent_id"]=>
        string(2) "42"
        ["title"]=>
        string(3) "PvP"
        ["link"]=>
        string(21) "http://localhost/pvp/"
        ["children"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you an see the code nests the child navigation under the parent navigation. This is so if I want to create a dropdown nav all I would need to do is iterate through the children array and generate the desired html.

HOWEVER

This only takes into account menus with one sub menu deep. What if you have a submenu of a submenu? Well that won't be taken into account.

My question(s) are as follows:

1) Is there a better way to do this? I want to use custom css and html structure.

2) How can I better structure my code and how can I recursively and dynamically take into consideration children -> children navigation sub menus / items?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: I loved the perseverance of your question. Keep the spirit. Actually when you are building your own query for making up a navigation menu, you are missing the awesome feature of WP navigation manager and all the built-in features using the `wp_nav_menu()`. The best way of making-up the WP nav menu with any custom classes is write a Nav_Walker class. There are many [bulma walker classes already available](https://www.google.com/search?q=bulma+nav+walker), though I tried none. A popular [Bootstrap nav walker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) is also available for your ref.